# What is emacsen-common package?

Tags: apt, emacs, delete

I was trying to remove emacs and all packages related and almost removed emacsen-common.
The output to `apt remove emacsen-common` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  atril-common bolt cinnamon-common cjs evince-common evolution-common evolution-data-server-common
  folks-common fonts-mathjax fwupd fwupd-amd64-signed gedit-common gedit-plugins-common gir1.2-champlain-0.12
  gir1.2-cmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gfbgraph-0.2
  gir1.2-ggit-1.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-graphene-1.0 gir1.2-gtkchamplain-0.12
  gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-handy-0.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-malcontent-0 gir1.2-meta-muffin-0.0
  gir1.2-mutter-7 gir1.2-nemo-3.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
  gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-control-center-data gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gnome-software-common gnome-todo-common gstreamer1.0-nice
  gstreamer1.0-pipewire libamtk-5-0 libamtk-5-common libappstream-glib8 libatrildocument3 libcaja-extension1
  libcamel-1.2-62 libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcjs0 libcolord-gtk1 libdee-1.0-4
  libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26
  libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-25 libevdocument3-4 libfarstream-0.2-5 libflashrom1 libflatpak0
  libfolks25 libfreerdp2-2 libftdi1-2 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin1 libgadu3 libgcab-1.0-0 libgdl-3-5
  libgdl-3-common libgdm1 libgit2-glib-1.0-0 libgnome-autoar-gtk-0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-todo
  libgpod-common libgpod4 libgspell-1-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libhandy-0.0-0 libimage-magick-perl
  libimage-magick-q16-perl libimagequant0 libjcat1 libjs-mathjax libkpathsea6 libmagick++-6.q16-8
  libmalcontent-0-0 libmalcontent-ui-0-0 libmeanwhile1 libmuffin0 libmutter-7-0 libnss-myhostname
  libostree-1-1 libpotrace0 libpst4 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libsgutils2-2 libsmbios-c2 libsynctex2
  libtepl-5-0 libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
  libunity9 libvncserver1 libwinpr2-2 libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1 libxmlb1 libytnef0 libzephyr4
  malcontent malcontent-gui metacity-common muffin-common mutter-common pidgin-data python-tinycss2-common
  python3-bs4 python3-evdev python3-html5lib python3-lxml python3-magic python3-mako python3-olefile
  python3-pampy python3-pil python3-scour python3-soupsieve python3-tinycss2 python3-tz python3-webencodings
  realmd shotwell-common switcheroo-control unoconv xdg-dbus-proxy xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
  xwayland yelp-xsl zenity-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbotan-2-17 libtspi1 thunderbird
Suggested packages:
  fonts-lyx
Recommended packages:
  myspell-en-us | hunspell-dictionary | myspell-dictionary
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aspell aspell-en aspell-es atril chrome-gnome-shell cinnamon cinnamon-control-center-goa cinnamon-core
  cinnamon-desktop-environment dictionaries-common emacsen-common enchant-2 evince evolution
  evolution-data-server evolution-plugin-bogofilter evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins gdm3 gedit
  gedit-plugin-bookmarks gedit-plugin-bracket-completion gedit-plugin-character-map gedit-plugin-code-comment
  gedit-plugin-color-picker gedit-plugin-color-schemer gedit-plugin-commander gedit-plugin-draw-spaces
  gedit-plugin-find-in-files gedit-plugin-git gedit-plugin-join-lines gedit-plugin-multi-edit
  gedit-plugin-session-saver gedit-plugin-smart-spaces gedit-plugin-synctex gedit-plugin-terminal
  gedit-plugin-text-size gedit-plugin-translate gedit-plugin-word-completion gedit-plugins gir1.2-evince-3.0
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome gnome-calendar gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-documents
  gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-maps gnome-online-accounts gnome-remote-desktop gnome-session gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extensions gnome-software gnome-sushi gnome-todo gnome-tweaks
  gnome-user-docs gnote hunspell-en-us hyphen-en-us inkscape ispanish libatrilview3 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libenchant-2-2 libevolution libevview3-3 libfolks-eds25 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgspell-1-2 libgtkspell0
  libgtkspell3-3-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libyelp0 lightdm-webkit2-greeter lutris muffin myspell-es
  mythes-en-us pidgin rhythmbox-plugins shotwell steam-launcher task-cinnamon-desktop task-gnome-desktop
  wspanish yelp zenity
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbotan-2-17 libtspi1 thunderbird
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 92 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 51.0 MB/52.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 178 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

What is that package, and why did it try to remove all those others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emacsen-common` provides shared infrastructure used by Emacs packages; in particular, it allows other packages to provide Emacs packages (in the Emacs sense, not the Debian sense), and register them with whichever implementation of Emacs is installed, if any.

Removing it causes many other packages to be removed because it’s a dependency of those packages, typically indirectly. In most cases, the connecting package is `dictionaries-common`, which provides shared infrastructure for dictionary package, and registers an Emacs package to simplify dictionary integration in Emacs.

For example, looking at the first and last packages in your list of to-be-removed packages:

```
$ aptitude why aspell emacsen-common
i A aspell              Depends dictionaries-common (> 0.40)
i A dictionaries-common Depends emacsen-common (>= 2.0.5)

$ aptitude why zenity emacsen-common
i A zenity               Depends  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.15.1)                                                                 
i A libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 Depends  libenchant-2-2 (>= 2.2.3)                                                                        
i A libenchant-2-2       Depends  hunspell-en-us | hunspell-dictionary | myspell-dictionary | aspell-dictionary | ispell-dictionary
i A hunspell-en-us       Depends  dictionaries-common                                                                              
i A dictionaries-common  Depends  emacsen-common (>= 2.0.5)
```

The `libenchant-2-2` connection explains many of the GNOME packages, including `gnome` itself (*via* `shotwell`).

Answer (score 0):

The command `apt show  emacsen-common` describes it as

> Common facilities for all emacsen

> This package contains code that is needed by all the (x)emacs
> packages.  It will be automatically installed when needed.

The output you show does not say it is removing all those packages.  It is saying if you remove emacsen, then all those other packages are no longer needed, so presumably, emacsen was the last package installed on your system that depends on some portion of that list of other packages.  Possibly some of those would be removed by `apt autoremove` even before you remove emacsen.

EDIT:

Investigating further, it appears that `emacsen-common` is depended on by `emacs-common` which is depended on by `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37` and removing that will remove most of gnome.  So ya, don't do that.

Comment: It says `The following packages will  be REMOVED:` and lists packages like cinnamon, gdm3 and gnome.

Comment: At the top it says `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:`  but you are right, it says removed further down on different packages.

Comment: I don’t think `emacs-common` is relevant here, there’s no strong dependency chain between `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37` and `emacs-common`.

Comment: I would think that too, but that's not what apt told me.

Comment: What’s `apt` telling you? `aptitude why -v libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 emacs-common` only finds weak dependency chains between the two packages.